# Enable developer options for on-device testing on Bixby 2.3.01.3

Tags: bixby

I have a Samsung Galaxy S9 with Bixby version 2.3.01.3 (voice version 1.0.26.0). I am trying to enable on-device testing of a private submission. According to [the docs](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/testing.on-device#enabling-on-device-testing), I need to "Open Bixby, go to Bixby's Settings, and tap 'About Bixby Voice.' On the About screen, tap the Bixby version number five times." It doesn't seem like that works though.

Here's exactly what I tried:

1. Press the Bixby button to bring up the Bixby home screen
2. Tap the three dots in the top right corner, click Settings
3. Scroll down to the very bottom and tap the button labeled "About Bixby" (I didn't see any button labeled "About Bixby Voice" so that was the closest I could find).
4. That brought up the screen below. Tapping on the version numbers 5+ times didn't seem to do anything.

[image: About Bixby Page]

Am I missing something here? Anybody has been able to successfully enable developer options?

More details about the device:

- Model SM-G960U1
- Android version 8.0.0
- Samsung Experience version 9.0

Comment: Which version of OS is the device on?

Comment: @MorrisonChang Updated the question with OS info

Comment: I was in your situation the other day, but let the phone update to Android 9 and other updates happened as well so I wasn't sure. Thanks for confirming the OS version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also have a Samsung Galaxy S9 SM-G690U1 device. I had to upgrade the System OS to:

> One UI Version 1.0
>
> Android 9

And Bixby Voice got upgraded to 2.1.24.0.

At that point the UI is in dark mode which matches existing documentation.

As a reminder you will have to disable `On-device testing` when you try to use Bixby normally, i.e. not testing a Private Submission.

Answer (score 0):

I was successfully able to enable Developer options following the same instructions. I don't know what I did differently from you.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Developer Options button in Bixby's settings. This is a hidden feature. To enable it, open Bixby, go to Bixby's Settings, and **tap "About Bixby Voice**." On the About screen, tap the Bixby version number **five times**. Bixby will inform you that developer options have been activated.

[enable on-device testing](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/testing.on-device)